# Getting InstantiationException when creating factory for a page using appium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, page-factory

I am running a test case using pagefactory method and have created an appium driver. I'm trying to initialising a page using pagefactory class like this:

The test class:

```
public class VerifyValidLogin {
    @Test
    public void CheckValidUser() throws MalformedURLException {
        AppiumDriver driver = DeviceFactory.CreateDriver();
        login login_page = PageFactory.initElements(driver, login.class);
    }
}
```

DeviceFactory class:

```
public class DeviceFactory {
  public static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;
  public static AppiumDriver CreateDriver() throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability( capabilityName: 'deviceName', value: 'Something');
    ...
    URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
    driver = new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(url,cap);
    System.out.print("Application started");
    return driver;
  }
}
```

Login class has element locators:

```
public class login {
    AppiumDriver driver;

    public login(AppiumDriver ldriver)
    {
        this.driver=ldriver;
    }

    @FindBy(how = How.XPATH,using ="xpath");
    MobileElement SignInButton;
}
```

But i'm not sure where i am doing wrong.

The error is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.Demo.pages.login
at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.instantiatePage(PageFactory.java:134)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:64)
at com.Demo.Testcases.VerifyValidLogin.CheckValidUser(VerifyValidLogin.java:18)
...
```

I am new to the automation testing so i'm not able to properly understand the error. Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 1):

Initialise elements in constructor

```
public login(AppiumDriver ldriver)
    {
        this.driver=ldriver;
        PageFactory.initElements(ldriver,this);
    }
```